# Как дописать QString в текстовый файл?

Tags: c++, qt

Подскажите как правильнее переписать функцию чтобы она дописывала в конец файла, а не заменяла

```
void Log::Add(QString log_message)
{
    QString out = "[";
    out += QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString();
    out += "] ";
    out += log_message;

    QFile file();
    if (file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
    {
        QTextStream stream(&file);
        stream << out;
        file.flush();
        file.close();
        if (stream.status() != QTextStream::Ok)
        {
            qDebug() << "Ошибка записи файла";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Надо открыть файл в режиме append. Читайте в документации описание  метода open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly|QIODevice::Append))
```

Comment: Прекрасно, и ещё бы кто бы каждую запись на новой строчке как сделать?

Comment: `stream << out << "\n";`?

Comment: Не работает, пробовал. Так тоже не работает stream << out << endl;